# why does textbox with height 0 still take up vertical real estate

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a textbox and I set the height to 0.

Just wondering why it is even visible or takes up any space at all.

```css
input {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Why not make it type hidden? Or use display: none?

Comment: @Rik Lewis It was just a matter of interest that I was asking.

Answer (score 4):

It is due to the `border` property of the input still remaining. Add

```
input {
  border: 0;
}
```

```css
input {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border:0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

it is the `border`

```css
input {
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border:0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```